# How to not display the # in the address bar

Tags: javascript, html

When we click `<a href="#" onclick="function();">Post data to server</a>`, the `#` is displayed at the end of the URL.

Is there a way to *not* have it displayed?

I have tried removing the `href="file.ext"` part, which works, though it produces unwanted results. It removed the color and underline styles of the hyperlink, making it appear to be just regular text.

Comment: If you're in the mood for angry yelling about web design philosophy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: Holy moly! over 700 upvotes lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the `javascript:void(0)` it wil not display

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="function();">Post data to server</a>
```

Comment: `javascript:;` is shorter and will do the same ;)

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about this. It's right there, staring me in the face all day long. *Shakes head*. Thank you Null.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the href to `javascript: void(0);`

Answer (score 1):

u can `return false` in the function